# ¿Como volver a renderizar el mismo componente con nueva información en React.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-axios

Quiero volver a renderizar un componente pero con diferente información, pero no funciona. Cuando vengo desde cualquier parte de la aplicación al componente que me muestra las palabras, me aparecen los valores.

Por ejemplo: Si al menú le doy el "Nouns", me muestra las `n3`, `n4` que pertenecen a la colección `nouns` en mongodb, pero si le doy click en "Verbs", **cambia la url pero no los valores en el componente**.

Si refresco la página con la url, con get_verbs se muestran v3, v4 que pertenecen a la colección `verbs`.

Para mostrar los `nouns` y `verbs` hago uso del mismo componente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo código de la barra de navegación haciendo uso de `Link`, de mi `Switch` en `App` y de como en el componente para mostrar las palabras debería renderizar las palabras de la colección correcta. Donde dependiendo del valor de la `url` hace la consulta a la API.

```
<ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                            <Link className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                                to="/">Know all the words</Link>
                            <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <Link className="dropdown-item" to="/get_nouns">Nouns</Link>
                                <Link className="dropdown-item" to="/get_verbs">Verbs</Link>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" to="/new_word">Insert new word</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Código del `Router`

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Navigation />
    <div className="container">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/new_word" render={()=> <InsertWord/>} />
        {/* Showing all the words by its type*/}
        <Route path="/get_nouns" render={(props)=> <GetWords {...props}/>} />
        <Route path="/get_verbs" render={(props)=> <GetWords {...props}/>} />
        <Route path="/edit_words/:id" render={(props)=> <EditWords {...props}/>} />
        <Route path="/" render={() => <Play/> } default/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

}

Funciones del componente a renderizar:

```
defineKindOfWord =  async(kind) => {
    try {
        if (kind === "/get_nouns") return await axios.get(baseURL + '/words/noun');
        if (kind === "/get_verbs") return await axios.get(baseURL + '/words/verb');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
getInfo = async () => {
    console.log(this.props.match.path);
    const getting = await this.defineKindOfWord(this.props.match.path)
    //const getting = await axios.get(baseURL + '/words/noun');
    console.log(getting.data.result);
    this.setState({ info: getting.data.result });
    //console.log(this.state.info);
}
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.getInfo();
```

Comment: Ok, no se renderiza de nuevo el componente cuando cambias la URL. Mirando por encima tu código ¿sólo llamas a `getInfo()` dentro de `componentDidMount()`? Este método sólo se llama al montar el componente, ¿Se esta montando con cada cambio de URL? Me parece que no, porque llamas al render al cambiar de URL, luego ya no se va a ejecutar de nuevo y tu información no cambia. Cambia el punto en el que traes la información. Ciclo de vida de un componente React: http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Answer (score 0):

Si la información la obtienes en un useEffect puedes hacer un estado que se ocupe de volver a ejecutar ese useEffect cuando tú quieras, te dejo un ejemplo.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [reloadUsers, setReloadUsers] = useState(false)


  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(getUsers());
    setReloadUsers(false)
  }, [reloadUsers])

  return (
    <div>
      ...Code
    </div>
  )
}
```

Ahora solo tienes que ejecutar el setReloadUsers(true); cuando quieras volver a pedir los datos de los usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

No hay forma de saber que es lo que quieres obtener en esas dos rutas

```
<Route path="/get_nouns" render={(props)=> <GetWords {...props}/>} />
<Route path="/get_verbs" render={(props)=> <GetWords {...props}/>} />
```

Ya que no envias ningun parámetro para diferenciar uno del otro
la unica es leer la url lo cual es poco practico
debes crear una sola ruta al comoponente y las variaciones deben ser parametros

asi

```
<Route path="/getdata/:tipo" render={(props)=> <GetWords {...props}/>} />
```

y en tu comoponente recibir ese parametro que se supone que es "get_nouns" o "get_verbs"

```
const GetWords = ({ computedMatch: { params } }) => {
  let { tipo } = params;

}
```